# How can I create a ListView of bitmap and string updating progressively after OnCreate?

Tags: android, listview, android-widget

I have a `ListView` on main activity, which shows a Contact picture on the left and a textview showing  on the right on each row. Everything works like it should, but the problem is that when application is launching,and when there is many messages, the user must wait about more than 10 seconds to start using the app.

What I tried to do was finding a way to load each row progressively, and avoid waiting every rows to be loaded to start using the app. I tried `AsyncTasks`, `Handlers`, `Threads`, `Hashmaps`.. But I can find a way to manage this task.

My Activity is a ListActivity.

the listview of the activity uses a custom Adapter with parameters (this,smsarray,picturearray). 
`smsarray` is an `ArrayList<String>` containing strings of each sms, and `picturearray` is an `ArrayList<Bitmap>` containing contact pictures in bitmap format for each sms.

I have a method `getSMSData()` which gets the sms strings and bitmaps with the help of a cursor, and puts strings at index 0 on smsarray, and bitmaps at index 0 on picturearray, for each contact on launch.

```
public class MessageList extends ListActivity {

static List<String> smsarray;   static List<Bitmap> picturearray;
static MessageListAdapter smsadapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    smsarray = new ArrayList<String>();
    picturearray = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

    getSMSData();

    smsadapter = new MessageListAdapter(this,smsarray,picturearray);    
    getListView().setAdapter(smsadapter);

}

public void getSMSData() {

        Bitmap defaultbitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.default_contact_picture);
        Bitmap contactbitmap;
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),new String [] {"person","address","body","date"} , null, null,"date ASC");
        String[] displayname = new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
        String name;
        String person;
        String address;
        String date;
        String body;
        int id; Cursor contactcursor;

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            person = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("person"));
            address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"));
            date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"));
            body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"));


            if (person != null){


                contactcursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, person),displayname, null, null, null);
                contactcursor.moveToFirst();
                name = contactcursor.getString(0);

                id = Integer.parseInt(person);
                InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(getContentResolver(), ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id));
                contactbitmap = null;

                if (input == null) {
                    contactbitmap = defaultbitmap;

                } else {
                    contactbitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                }

                if (contactbitmap != null){
                    picturearray.add(0,contactbitmap);
                }else {
                    picturearray.add(0,defaultbitmap);
                }

                smsarray.add(0,getResources().getString(R.string.From) +" "+name+" "+"\n"+getResources().getString(R.string.Number)+" "+address+" " +"\n"+getResources().getString(R.string.At) +" "+date+"\n"+getResources().getString(R.string.Message)+" "+body);


            }

            if (person == null) {
                picturearray.add(0,defaultbitmap);
                smsarray.add(0,getResources().getString(R.string.From) +" "+getResources().getString(R.string.Unknown)+" "+"\n"+getResources().getString(R.string.Number)+" "+address+" " +"\n"+getResources().getString(R.string.At) +" "+date+"\n"+getResources().getString(R.string.Message)+" "+body);

            }

        }

    }


}

public class MessageListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter <String> {

final Context vcontext;
final List<String> varray;
final List<Bitmap> vpicture;
final LayoutInflater layoutinflater; 

public MessageListAdapter (Context context,List<String> smsarray, List<Bitmap> picturearray) {
    super(context, 0);
    vcontext = context;
    varray = smsarray;
    vpicture = picturearray;
    this.layoutinflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }

public int getCountpicture() {

    return vpicture.size();
}

public Bitmap getItempicture(int position) {

    return vpicture.get(position);
}

public long getItemIdpicture(int position) {

    return position; 
}

public int getCount() {

    return varray.size();
}

public String getItem(int position) {

    return varray.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position; 
}

public  class ViewHolder {
    TextView messagetext;
    ImageView image;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null){
        convertView = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder ();

        holder.messagetext = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.messagetext);
        holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contactimage);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.image.setImageBitmap(vpicture.get(position));
    holder.image.setPadding(2, 1, 0, 0);

    holder.messagetext.setText(varray.get(position));
    holder.messagetext.setPadding(10, -1, 10, 5);

    return convertView;

}

}
```

Thanks for your precious help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of decoding all the bitmaps and retrieving all the records initially, you should be doing it in the `getView()` method of your `MessageListAdapter`. Pass the Cursor in the constructor and use it from inside the adapter.

EDIT :

You could modify your getSMSData() method to something like this :

```
public Cursor getSMSData() {
     Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),new String [] {"person","address","body","date"} , null, null,"date ASC");
     return cursor;
}
```

and in your `onCreate` use this cursor to create the `MessageListAdapter` like this:

```
Cursor cursor = getSMSData();
smsadapter = new MessageListAdapter(this, cursor);
```

Modify the `MessageListAdapter` constructor to receive and save the cursor:

```
public MessageListAdapter (Context context,Cursor cursor) {
    super(context, 0);
    vcontext = context;
    vcursor = cursor;
    this.layoutinflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); // alternately, you could use the View.inflate() method
}
```

Then use this cursor in the `getView` method of your adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // ...
    vcursor.moveToPosition(position);
    // Now use this cursor to populate your convertView
    return convertView;
}
```

This way you only have to load data for the rows which is visible to the user. I hope that helps.

If you think that decoding the contact picture for each record (everytime the getView method is called) is slowing you down, you might consider saving the contact picture in a Map (but DO NOT decode all the pictures initially by iterating over the entire cursor. That'll put you back at square one) and load it from there.
You could also consider using `AsyncTask` to load the contact pictures, but since you are using the `convertView` you need to be careful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ; ) I will work hard on it. Can you please guide me a little more on how I should do it,it will definitely save me from this burden my app is almost finished. thanks.

Comment: @user1079001 I have added code snippets to my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It should definitly work this way =))

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get everything done with the setting of a CursorAdapter. Now my adapter gets directly with the cursor the number, the date, the message and the id of the contact if it exists, in my bindView method, but I can't figure out how to set contact's name if there is an id. I thought this will work :

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

String contact = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("person"));
TextView contacttext = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.from);
             String name = "";

                if(contact == null) {
                    name = "unknown";
                }

                if(contact != null) {
                    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,contact);
                    Cursor contactnamecursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
                    name = contactnamecursor.getString(contactnamecursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                }

             contacttext.setText(name);
}
```

But it seems that I can't use a new cursor in my CursorAdapter. It gives me an exception when I scroll through the list (when it gets to a row where it should display contact's name, normaly) Why can't I use my new contactnamecursor? I also tried with the adapter's cursor but it gives me an exception as well... I will try differents methods, but learning why it fails should help me and other readers to improve their knowledge if you have the answer ; )

Comment: I found the issue! I just forgot to add contactnamecursor.moveToFirst(); before name = contactnamecursor......